# As if as though

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, clauses, complements

I am having a problem identifing which gramatical function as if (as though, like) has

As far as I know

- After linking verbs, we have noun/ noun phrase/ noun clause and adjective/ adjective phrase which act as subjective complement.
- "As if" is conjunction introducing subordinating clause, or adverbial clause

And then, the sentences I have just read (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/vi/grammar/british-grammar/as-if-and-as-though) leaves me confused.

> The floods were rising and it was as if it was the end of the world.
>
> It looks as if they’ve had a shock.

I cannot say "it looks" in isolation. So, I think of why an subordinating clause stand right behind linking verbs, where it has to be a noun or adj. Or I have made a mistake while analyzing those structures

It V[**looks**] ADV CLAUSE[(**as if**) (conjunction) + (**they’ve had a shock**) (clause)].

Please let me know as simple as posible because my language is not good enough yet. Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. Both _as_ and _if_ have separate uses, and their combination has its own, as well. You need special verbs (not "linking verbs" - that phrase is just handwaving) that are either auxiliary like _be_ or perceptual, like _seem, look, sound_. The _as if_ complex conjunction introduces a tensed clause, and in this construction one may substitute _like_ for _as if_.

Comment: @JohnLawler "You need special verbs . . . that are either auxiliary like be or perceptual, like seem, look, sound." <-- I don't quite follow this. E.g.: "He ran the last mile as if his life depended on it."

Comment: In the constructions in the example, _it looks as if_ and _it is as if_ are what is being referred to. They have their own syntax. In your example, it works differently - no verb, no subject, just a manner/means adverbial clause.

Comment: I'd appreciate your help, thank you both